# how to click an input where a td is empty?

Tags: xpath

I have this table like this

```js
var tdCnt=0;
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $('<input />', {
            type : 'checkbox',
            id : 'td' + tdCnt,
            class : 'dt-checkboxes',
            value : name
        }).appendTo($(this).find("td").eq(0));
        tdCnt++;
    });
```

```css
.dt-checkboxes {
float :left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<td></td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>25</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>30</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I just want to click the inputs where the 4th td is empty how can I achieve that?
this is the code im using, but it keeps clicking the ones that are not empty

```
(//input[@type='checkbox' and //td[4]/descendant::div[string-length()=0]])[$counter]
```

or this one

```
   (//input[@type='checkbox' and //td[4][not(text())]])[2]
```

and neither works, it keeps clicking the ones that are not empty how can I achieve this?
Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete, 3 ways to select an empty `td` element (in your case : the fourth) :

```
//tr/td[4][.=""]
//tr/td[4][string-length()=0]
//tr/td[4][not(text())]
```

Regarding your sample data, you have one `checkbox` per `tr` element. To select '*inputs where the 4th td is empty*', you can use :

```
//tr/td[4][.=""]/preceding::input[1][@type='checkbox']
//tr/td[4][.=""]/../td/input[@type='checkbox']
```

The first will look for the empty `td` element, then its first preceding `input` element containing a specific attribute.
The second will look for the empty `td` element, then the child of its parent (ie : the `input` element).

or if I fix your second try :

```
//input[@type='checkbox'][ancestor::tr[1]/td[4][.=""]]
```

Look anywhere for an `input` element whith a specific attribute. And where the fourth `td` element, child of its first `tr` ancestor, is empty.

Output : `2` inputs nodes